# ReactJS Error when using map function, cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a sport/tinder like app for a school project from a friend of mine. It came together well on my localhost, but for him it was a requirement to host it online. Not really a professional in hosting, but I was a bit familiar with Heroku. I used a client and a server side for my application, so I build the client side and put it into the server side folder. This server side is hosted on the Heroku page. But whenever I try to login, it won't work and I get this error message in my console.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

The error says it is caused by this line of code.

```
const matchedUserIds = matches.map(({user_id}) => user_id)
```

This is the whole MatchDisplay file that is used in my Dashboard. I'm using a MongoDB for the storage of my users.

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";

const MatchesDisplay = ({ matches, setClickedUser }) => {
    const [matchedProfiles, setMatchedProfiles] = useState(null);
    const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies(null);
    const [matched, setMatched] = useState(null);

    const matchedUserIds = matches.map(({ user_id }) => user_id);

    const userId = cookies.UserId;

    const getMatches = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(
                "https://[app].herokuapp.com/users",
                {
                    params: { userIds: JSON.stringify(matched()) },
                }
            );
            setMatchedProfiles(response.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getMatches();
    }, [matches]);

    const filteredMatchedProfiles = matchedProfiles?.filter(
        (matchedProfile) =>
            matchedProfile.matches.filter(
                (profile) => profile.user_id === userId
            ).length > 0
    );

    return (
        <div className="matches-display">
            {filteredMatchedProfiles?.map((match) => (
                <div
                    key={match.user_id}
                    className="match-card"
                    onClick={() => setClickedUser(match)}
                >
                    <div className="img-container">
                        <img
                            src={match?.url}
                            alt={match?.first_name + "profile"}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <h3>{match?.first_name}</h3>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};
export default MatchesDisplay;
```

Any help is welcome. If you need more code examples, please reply ;)

**EDIT**

The ChatContainer that passes the user to the MatchesDisplay.

```html
import ChatHeader from "./ChatHeader";
import MatchesDisplay from "./MatchesDisplay";
import ChatDisplay from "./ChatDisplay";
import { useState } from 'react';

const ChatContainer = ({user}) => {
    const [ clickedUser, setClickedUser] = useState(null)

    return (
        <div className="chat-container">
            <ChatHeader user={user}/>

            <div>
                <button className="option" onClick={() => setClickedUser(null)}>Matches</button>
                <button className="option" disabled={!clickedUser}>Chat</button>
                <button className="option" >Prices</button>
            </div>

            {!clickedUser && <MatchesDisplay matches={user.matches} setClickedUser={setClickedUser}/>}

            {clickedUser && <ChatDisplay user={user} clickedUser={clickedUser}/>}
        </div>
    )
}

export default ChatContainer
```

The Dashboard that passes the user to the Chatcontainer.

```html
import TinderCard from 'react-tinder-card';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {useCookies} from 'react-cookie';
import ChatContainer from '../components/ChatContainer'
import axios from "axios";

const Dashboard = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
    const [genderedUsers, setGenderedUsers] = useState(null)
    const [lastDirection, setLastDirection] = useState(null)
    const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies(['user'])
    const [matchedUserIds, setMatchedUserIds] = useState(null)
    const [filteredGenderedUsers, setFilteredGenderedUsers] = useState(null)

    const userId = cookies.UserId
    const getUser = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('https://funfit-webpage.herokuapp.com/user', {
                params: {userId}
            })
            return setUser(response.data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    const getGenderedUsers = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('https://funfit-webpage.herokuapp.com/gendered-users', {
                params: {gender: user?.gender_interest}
            })
            return setGenderedUsers(response.data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getUser()
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        setMatchedUserIds(user?.matches.map(({user_id}) => user_id).concat(userId))
        if (user) return getGenderedUsers()
    }, [user])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (genderedUsers) {
            return setFilteredGenderedUsers(genderedUsers?.filter(
                genderedUser => !matchedUserIds.includes(genderedUser.user_id)
            ))
        }
    }, [genderedUsers])

    const updateMatches = async (matchedUserId) => {
        try {
            await axios.put('https://funfit-webpage.herokuapp.com/addmatch', {
                userId,
                matchedUserId
            })
            return getUser()
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    const swiped = (direction, swipedUserId) => {
        console.log(direction, swipedUserId)
        if (direction === 'right') {
            updateMatches(swipedUserId)
        }
        return setLastDirection(direction)
    }

    const outOfFrame = (name) => {
        console.log(name + ' left the screen!')
    }


    return (<>
        {user && <div className="dashboard">
            <ChatContainer user={user}/>
            <div className="swipe-container">
                <div className="card-container">
                    {filteredGenderedUsers?.map((genderedUser) =>
                        <TinderCard
                            className='swipe'
                            key={genderedUser.user_id}
                            onSwipe={(dir) => swiped(dir, genderedUser.user_id)}
                            onCardLeftScreen={() => outOfFrame(genderedUser.first_name)}>
                            <div style={{backgroundImage: 'url(' + genderedUser.url + ')'}} className='card'>
                                <h3>{'Name: ' + genderedUser.first_name} <br/> {'Sport: ' + genderedUser.about}</h3>
                            </div>
                        </TinderCard>)}
                    <div className="swipe-info">
                        {lastDirection ? <p>You swiped {lastDirection}</p> : <p/>}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>}
    </>)
}
export default Dashboard
```

Comment: Where is the component that's passing props into this component?

Comment: @yainspan I added the components below the **EDIT** inside my question. I hope this clarifies my problem.

Comment: You are assuming 
    
`user.matches`

is an array and you are trying to use .map() method on it.

However, `user.matches` is not an array. It may be an object or even `null` or `undefined`.

You should probably first figure out where exactly are you getting or setting `user.matches` value and start from there